# How do you get this shape in HTML?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Can someone help me write plain html and css code for the below shape ?
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shapes.asp

Answer (score 1):

HTML/CSS

```css
.shape {
  clip-path: polygon(0 19%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 81%);
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='shape'></div>
```

And you can make any shapes you want with clip path.
Try this website to make shapes https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: i want a rotated trapezoid as shown in the picture

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Transparent Borders**

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    border: 40px solid;
    border-top-color: #00000000;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #00000000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Multiple backgrounds**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, black 50%, white 51%) 0 0/100% 25% no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom left, black 50%, white 51%) 0 100%/100% 25% no-repeat, black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Pseudo Elements**

```css
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50px;
    background: black;
}

div:before,div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}

div:before {
    top: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left,black 50%,white 51%) top/100% no-repeat ;
}

div:after {
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left,black 50%,white 51%) bottom/100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: aside clip-path, you also have transform not answered yet ;) https://jsfiddle.net/ymn39buo/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I thought about that But it would require nesting of elements and awkward positioning if you plan on adding content.